# Office-JS GetFileAsync in Excel not returning the ThumbnailPart

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

A couple of days ago the "getFileAsync" started working in the Insiders Fast release for Excel. That was great news!

But now I running into an difference in the behavior between Excel and Word & Powerpoint. When I use getFileAsync for example on a powerpoint document, I can extract the "ThumbnailPart" by using OpenXml. In there the thumbnail for the document are stored.

For Excel the Thumbnailpart is always null! If I access the Excel document directly with OpenXML there is a ThumbnailPart available, but getting the same Excel file via "getFileAsync", seems to remove the thumbnail part.
Is this functionality yet to come, or is there another way of getting or creating a thumbnail from within a Office Add-in?

Thank you!

Comment: Let me pass this on to the developer that implemented the feature...

Comment: Hi Michael,
Thank you very much for picking this up. If you need more input or have any updates, please let me know!